Geometry nodes - make instance on point of curve follow rotation
I am trying to create a sort of cable, using geometry nodes on a curve. Here's how it looks like now vs how I want it to look (sketch on the right side)

Here's what my geometry nodes look like:

The top part is for the curve that will simply be resampled and converted to a mesh. The resampling points I also use in the bottom part, to generate those cylinders that will appear on points along the way of the curve. However I cannot for the life of me get those cylinders to be rotated along the curve correctly.
I read in a tutorial that I should use "Align rotation to vector" and plug it into the "instance on points" node, so I did that, but it doesn't do anything at all for me.
I uploaded the blend-file here: https://shorturl.at/ZoqvG

You're nearly there, but use a CurveTangent instead of a Normal node and change the AlignRotationtoVector direction to X and increase the Factor to 1.

Incidentally you can delete the TranslateInstances node. It isn't actually doing anything.

Thank you!!! That did the trick :)

No problem. I've just added a bit below the image in my answer.
